# libpython3.6m.dylib vs libpython3.6.dylib

Tags: python

I'm working on creating an app from Python code using py2app.

Everything goes well until I run setup.py, then at the very end of it running I get this message: "ValueError:

'/Users/(my_computer_name)/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6.dylib' does not exist"

It turns out there is a file there, just named slightly different: It asks for 'libpython3.6.dylib' and there is a file named 'libpython3.6m.dylib'

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda Python binaries are build with multithread support and that means the library generated will have the form `*m.dylib` ( [see this Google Groups link](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/4HKVl8Jhy9E) )

You could create a symlink and try to build using py2app (I had issues with that).

Alternatively this worked for me: I had an equivalent virtualenv setup (which uses a Python Framework and makes py2app locate the library differently) and was able to build the application on that one.